# r function to add to a dataframe columns from named vectors

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to add named vectors, extracted from a list, to a dataframe using a function (I have tons of such vectors to add).
I'm starting from an empty dataframe and wish to add a vector which name appears in a vector.

Let's begin with a very simple example:

```
set <-c("c1", "c190", "c200","c66")

fun1<-function(z){
    dataf <-data.frame(matrix(, nrow=4))
    v1<-c(1, 2, 3, 4)
    for(i in z){
    dataf[i] <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
    }   
    return(dataf)
    }
test <- fun1(set)
```

And that's working perfectly! For instance, `test$c1` gives me the right vector with the right values.

Now, I try to do it for my data, and that's a bit more complicated.
I have a year vector, as year<-c("y2003", "y2004",etc...)
I also have a variables dataframe named variables, with data vectors for each set of variable "c1", "c2" etc. Basically colnames(variables)==set.
In previous example, the vector I wish to get was exogeneous (c(1, 2, 3, 4)), now I first need to compute it:

```
rci_set <- function(x, y, set){ #x is a list, y my year vector and set the UNIQUE variable I wish to get the data from
    vector <-c()
    for(i in y){
    vector <-c(vector, x[[i]][set])
    }
    vector2<-as.numeric(vector)
    return(vector2)
    }
```

Again, that's working perfectly!

Then, I'd like to loop it for all my sets:

```
all_rci<-function(x, y, z){ #x is the same list, y the same year vector, z the set vector I wish to loop
    dataf <-data.frame()
    for(i in z){
        dataf[i] <- rbind(dataf, data.frame(rci_set(x, y, z[i]))) 
        }
    return(dataf)
    }
```

And that's not working, I get an error: "Column `NA` not found"
I've checked several times and there are no columns named NA in all my data. What went wrong ?
Maybe I could do it more quickly with an apply function, but again, I didn't manage to found how.

Thanks a lot for any help you might provide :)

Comment: If you edit your question to include sample input (in a copy/pasteable format) and desired output, I'll take a look. Include example column names and data for 3 columns, 3 or 4 values each.

Comment: Thanks again for your very kind help, Gregor. I've actually asked another more useful question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47967129/r-getting-in-the-right-order-the-results-of-a-lapply-function-with-arguments-f . It follows something you actually asked me and that I was too slow to answer in time.